# ATF and Eclipse ecourred "Error initializing the web browser"

Tags: eclipse

i had ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and i installed Eclipse with PDT and ATF.I encontered follow Error when I run php project:

> Error initializing the web browser.
>   No more handles (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
>       no swt-xulrunner-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
>       no swt-xulrunner-gtk in java.library.path
>       Can't load library: /home/mehdi/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-xulrunner-gtk-3740.so
>       Can't load library: /home/mehdi/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-xulrunner-gtk.so
>   )

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`.

Try the command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

That solves my problems with the internal browser in SpringSource Tool Suite under 12.04 x64.

Comment: thanks for your replay.this was installed.i find out ATF incompatibility 64-bit.